# python remove tup[0] duplicates from list of tuples

Tags: python, list, tuples

`input = [("abc", 2), ("def", 7), ("abc", 6), ("ghi", 2), ("ghi", 5)]`

I want to remove the tup[0] duplicates `("abc", 6)` and `("ghi", 5)` from the list, so the output should be:

`output = [("abc", 2), ("def", 7), ("ghi", 2)]`

How do I do this?

Comment: Can you give an example of what you have tried so far? Where are you stuck?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are more elegant solutions, but this worked.

```
input = [("abc", 2), ("def", 7), ("abc", 6), ("ghi", 2), ("ghi", 5)]

output = []
first_tups = []

for tup in input:
    if tup[0] not in first_tups:
        output.append(tup)
        first_tups.append(tup[0])

print(output)
```

output

```
[('abc', 2), ('def', 7), ('ghi', 2)]
```

Answer (score 2):

Just use a `set` to keep track of the first items youv'e already seen:

```
>>> input_data = [("abc", 2), ("def", 7), ("abc", 6), ("ghi", 2), ("ghi", 5)]
>>> seen = set()
>>> result = []
>>> for tup in input_data:
...     s = tup[0]
...     if s not in seen:
...         seen.add(s)
...         result.append(tup)
...
>>> result
[('abc', 2), ('def', 7), ('ghi', 2)]
```